# Is the interior wall separating my living room, dining room, family room, and kitchen a load bearing wall?

Tags: walls, structural, load-bearing, removal

I am a first time homebuyer and would like to remove the large wall separating my living room, dining room, family room, and kitchen prior to redoing all of the floors in my new home. Can someone please help me out and tell me if the wall is a load bearing wall? I was able to obtain the blueprints for the home from city hall. Thanks so much for your help!

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since the home is one level and the roof is noted as "pre-engineered truss" you have no load-bearing wall there. Modify at will.

Comment: Thank you for the response!